# Search by model to display categories

Tags: magento2, category, model, search, category-attribute

I'm trying to figure out the workflow for my redesign on Magento2. I would like a search by model feature ( year, make, model). But instead of having a disorganized list of products, I would like it to open a category with subcategories filled with specific products. Is it something possible?

Ultimately I would push it a step further and have a "build your own" workflow where the client is pushed through each category one after the other and fill up the shopping cart with goodies.I haven't seen something like that out of the box and I don't even know where to start to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

For  **search like model feature ( year, make, model)**.You  need to do customization, magento does not has this type of search.

Magento has **advance search concept** but it  **does not fill your requirement**.So you need to  build an extension  and implement your business logic on it.

Or,For your requirement, you can use  [Amasty Product Parts Finder](https://amasty.com/product-parts-finder-for-magento-2.html)  extension.

I was requirement and it has fullfill by this extension.

Comment: I've seen a couple of these extensions, but they are all meant to create a lit of products. I would like the search result to be a category specific to that vehicle.